# C++ Rotation matrix issue when used on a square

Tags: c++, windows, matrix

I'm attempting to apply an a rotation matrix in C++ that rotates all points of square a specified degree around a specified origin. The catch is that it is based in the win32 console, so each point has to correspond with a pair of ints, rather than floating point values. As you can see below, the rotating square's overall shape is consistent with the desired result, but there are a number of 'holes' in it.

Here's my source code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;

enum {W = 50, H = 50, S = 25}; //Width, Height, Square size

struct Vector2i
{
    int x;
    int y;
    Vector2i() {}
    Vector2i(int _x, int _y) : x(_x), y(_y) {}
};

struct Square
{
    bool Data[W][H];
    Vector2i Origin = Vector2i(W / 2, H / 2);

    void clear() {
        for (int y = 0; y < H; ++y) {
            for (int x = 0; x < W; ++x)
                Data[x][y] = false;
        }
    }

    void setSquare() {
        for (int y = H / 2 - S / 2; y < H / 2 + S / 2; ++y) {
            for (int x = W / 2 - S / 2; x < W / 2 + S / 2; ++x)
                Data[x][y] = true;
        }
    }

    void draw() {
        for (int y = 0; y < H; ++y) {
            for (int x = 0; x < W; ++x) {
                if (y == Origin.y && x == Origin.x) std::cout << '+'; //Marks the origin
                else if (Data[x][y]) std::cout << 'X';
                else std::cout << '.';
            }
            std::cout << '\n';
        }
    }
};

Vector2i newPos(Vector2i old, double theta) {
    theta *= 3.14159265d / 180.d; //Converting from degrees to radians

    int X = ceil(cos(theta) * old.x - sin(theta) * old.y);
    int Y = ceil(sin(theta) * old.x + cos(theta) * old.y);

    return Vector2i(X, Y);
}

int main()
{
    cout << "Enter an angle (in degrees): ";
    double angle = 0;
    cin >> angle;

    Square One;
    One.clear();
    One.setSquare();
    One.draw();

    Square Two;
    Two.clear();

    ///Draw the rotated square as the second square
    for (int y = 0; y < H; ++y) {
        for (int x = 0; x < W; ++x) {
            if (One.Data[x][y]) {
                Vector2i finalVec = newPos(Vector2i(x - One.Origin.x, 
                                                    y - One.Origin.y), angle);
                Two.Data[finalVec.x + One.Origin.x][finalVec.y + One.Origin.y] = true;
            }
        }
    }

    ///Copy the second square back into the first
    for (int y = 0; y < H; ++y) {
        for (int x = 0; x < W; ++x)
            One.Data[x][y] = Two.Data[x][y];
    }

    One.draw();

    return 0;
}
```

Is this due to the accuracy of the `newPos()` function, or is it the rounding into `int` values that is causing this?

Additionally, is there a way to fix this or predict where the holes will be?

[image: Before rotation]
[image: After rotation, with holes.]

**EDIT: SOLVED!**

Going off of infgeoax's suggestion to work backwards, I created a function to calculate the original positions. I'll leave the augmented code here, in case anyone has a similar problem in the future (Thanks for all your help, everyone! [especially infgeoax, for the brainwave]):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;

enum {W = 50, H = 50, S = 25};

struct Vector2i
{
    int x;
    int y;
    Vector2i() {}
    Vector2i(int _x, int _y) : x(_x), y(_y) {}
};

struct Square
{
    bool Data[W][H];;
    Vector2i Origin = Vector2i(W / 2, H / 2);

    void clear() {
        for (int y = 0; y < H; ++y) {
            for (int x = 0; x < W; ++x)
                Data[x][y] = false;
        }
    }

    void setSquare() {
        for (int y = H / 2 - S / 2; y < H / 2 + S / 2; ++y) {
            for (int x = W / 2 - S / 2; x < W / 2 + S / 2; ++x)
                Data[x][y] = true;
        }
    }

    void draw() {
        for (int y = 0; y < H; ++y) {
            for (int x = 0; x < W; ++x) {
                if (y == Origin.y && x == Origin.x) std::cout << '+'; //Marks the origin
                else if (Data[x][y]) std::cout << 'X';
                else std::cout << '.';
            }
            std::cout << '\n';
        }
    }
};

Vector2i oldPos(Vector2i new_, float theta) {
    theta *= 3.14159265f / 180.f; //Converting from degrees to radians
    return Vector2i(new_.x * cosf(theta) + new_.y * sinf(theta) + 0.5f,
                    new_.y * cosf(theta) - new_.x * sinf(theta) + 0.5f);
}

int main()
{
    cout << "Enter an angle (in degrees): ";
    float angle = 0;
    cin >> angle;

    Square One;
    One.clear();
    One.setSquare();
    One.draw();

    Square Two;
    Two.clear();

    for (int y = 0; y < H; ++y) {
        for (int x = 0; x < W; ++x) {
            Vector2i vec = oldPos(Vector2i(x - One.Origin.x, y - One.Origin.y), angle);
            vec.x += One.Origin.x;
            vec.y += One.Origin.y;
            if (vec.x >= 0 && vec.x < W && vec.y >= 0 && vec.y < H)
                Two.Data[x][y] = One.Data[vec.x][vec.y];
        }
    }

    Two.draw();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `Is this due to the accuracy of the newPos()?`  What did you discover when debugging your program?

Comment: @Laserbreath: Can you show a picture of the results?

Comment: I don't see how you are going to increase accuracy by switching from `int` to floating point back to `int`.  The conversions will lose some accuracy.  I suggest you use **Fixed Point**.

Comment: There are issues rotating a square an "odd" number of degrees in a high resolution, GUI environment, let alone console.  Don't know what you were really expecting.

Comment: To avoid visual holes, you need to increase the resolution of your array so that there are, say, 4 or 9 array elements per console character.  But it might be preferable to just rotate the four corners of the square, and then draw lines between them.

Comment: IMHO you could only rotate the four vertices that define the square (rectangle), then fill the rotated rectangle with 'X's. Less computation and no more holes. :-P

Comment: Thank you for all the suggestions! @ThomasMatthews: To answer your question, I was hoping that computing with floating points would make the rounding back to `int` slightly more accurate.

Comment: @HarryJohnston: That's a great suggestion actually, I'll try that.

Comment: @infgeoax: The reason I was hesitant to do this was because ideally (not that I specified this) the original rectangle wouldn't have been a single colour, so it would be necessary to compute every point.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well your problem has nothing to do with whether or not your are developing a console or GUI application. Images are stored and processed as matrices of pixels. When you rotate the image, the resulting position for a specific pixel is usually not integers.

The idea is to go the other way around.

1. You calculate the four corners of the rotated sqaure.
2. For each position(pixel) in the rotated square, you calculate its color by rotating it back to the original square.